# Loading dynamic url using ajax .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple pages that I need to load dynamically whenever a load more button is click

```
http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged=1
http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged=2
http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged=3
http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged=4
```

By default http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged=1 will load up, so if I click on the load more button I need to append the new content into the page but instead of loading from page 1 I will need to load from page 2,3 and 4 every time I click on the load more button.

How do I make a ajax call that will work with multiple urls?

I used jQuery ajax .load but the problem is the nextLink variable will not be updated since it is already loaded in the js file.

```
var url = "http://example.com/?page_id=1208&paged="
var pageNum = 1;
var nextLink =url+pageNum;

 $('.content-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink + ' .each-block',
    function() {
        pageNum++;
    }
);
```

Comment: what do you mean? you need to provide more explanation

Comment: @erkaner just updated, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

class eqals `content1`

```
 $('.content-'+ pageNum).load(nextLink, function() {
        pageNum++;
    }
);
```